# Perform an automatic Save As in Preview

Tags: applescript, save-as

I'd like to have Preview open a pdf and save it to another folder, or save it with a different name to the same folder (not sure which method is needed yet).

I can open the file fine from a specific folder location.

I tried invoking the Save As command, but I don't want the user to have to perform this step, I want to do it automatically to avoid user data entry errors.

Here are the steps that work:

```
set the save_location to "/FolderOne/FolderTwo/FolderThree/"
set the file_name to "Past Due.pdf"

tell application "Preview"
    open file "FolderOne:FolderTwo:Past Due.pdf"
    tell application "Preview" to activate

    tell application "System Events" to keystroke "S" using {option down, shift down, command down}

end tell
```

Comment: Question: do you actually need to open this in preview for some reason, or are you just trying to copy the file to a new location? The latter is trivially easy, if you don't actually have to do anything in Preview (aside from open and save)...

Comment: The request is to make a copy of the original PDF in a fixed location, open the copy and allow it to be annotated in Preview (or perhaps a different app)

Answer (score 0):

This following AppleScript code will display a dialog for you to choose your original PDF file to be duplicated, display a dialog for you to name your duplicated file, and display a dialog for you to choose a location to save your duplicated file.  It will then open your duplicated file in Preview.app, leaving your original un-opened.

This AppleScript code works for me using the latest version of macOS Mojave.

```
property originalLocation : missing value
property originalFileName : missing value
property originalFileNameExtension : missing value
property moveToLocation : missing value
property newFileName : missing value

activate
set originalFile to (choose file with prompt ¬
    "Choose Which Document To Duplicate & Open In Preview.app")

tell application "System Events"
    set fileInfo to originalFile's properties
    set {originalFileName, originalFileNameExtension, originalLocation} to ¬
        {name of fileInfo, name extension of fileInfo, (path of fileInfo) as alias}
end tell

set theOffset to offset of originalFileNameExtension in originalFileName
set shortName to text 1 thru (theOffset - 2) of originalFileName

activate
set newFileName to text returned of (display dialog ¬
    "Choose A Name For Your Duplicate File" default answer ¬
    (shortName & " Copy") as text buttons {"Cancel", "OK"} ¬
    default button 2 cancel button 1 ¬
    with title "Choose A Name For Your File" with icon 1 ¬
    giving up after 120) & "." & originalFileNameExtension

activate
set moveToLocation to (choose folder with prompt ¬
    ("Choose A Save To Location For " & newFileName) ¬
        default location originalLocation) as text

do shell script "cp " & quoted form of POSIX path of originalFile & ¬
    " " & quoted form of POSIX path of ((moveToLocation & newFileName) as text)

do shell script "open -b com.apple.Preview " & ¬
    quoted form of POSIX path of ((moveToLocation & newFileName) as text)
```